# Formatting string object into hours:minutes:seconds python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

I have an object in a data frame `timeStarted_timeWhenPuzzlesShownOnScreen` and need to convert it into a time object. Some values however have different formats. How would I be able to go about
turning the strings shown in the picture below into `hours:minutes: seconds` in python?

[image]

Comment: [**PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Answer (score -1):

The `dateutil` module will do what you want, with a bit of fiddling with the times expressed as integers.

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parser
>>> p = parser()
>>> p.parse("13:35:53")
datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 19, 13, 35, 53)
>>> p.parse("23:05:50")
datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 19, 23, 5, 50)
```

To get the colons into the integers, you can do

```
>>> a = str(230550)
>>> f"{a[:2]}:{a[2:4]}:{a[4:]}"
'23:05:50'
```

Answer (score -1):

Very ugly but it might work.

Having this dataframe:

```
        timeStarted_timeWhenPuzzlesShowScreen
  0                              10:06:43
  1                                113507
```

If you run:

```
pd.to_datetime(data['timeStarted_timeWhenPuzzlesShowScreen'], \
format='%H:%M:%S',errors='coerce').fillna \
(pd.to_datetime(data['timeStarted_timeWhenPuzzlesShowScreen'], \
format='%H%M%S',errors='coerce'))
```

You get the rows as datetimes64:

```
0   1900-01-01 10:06:43
1   1900-01-01 11:35:07
Name: timeStarted_timeWhenPuzzlesShowScreen, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```